# user authentication check using sts token instead of user/pass

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am new to aws cognito. Here is what I am trying to do:

I have some users and I want them to login to my website and then as far as their session is valid I would like to keep them in without forcing them to sign in. So as far as I understand I need to generate  STS token using cognito and send to the user and then in the next calls user will send the sts token as a header and I check the sts token using cognito and if it is valid I will serve the users.

For that I use the instruction in the following link:

https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/

So specifically I use this part to authenticate the user and establish session:

```
var authenticationData = {
    Username : 'username',
    Password : 'password',
};
var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
var poolData = {
    UserPoolId : '...', // Your user pool id here
    ClientId : '...' // Your client id here
};
var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
var userData = {
    Username : 'username',
    Pool : userPool
};
var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());

        //POTENTIAL: Region needs to be set if not already set previously elsewhere.
        AWS.config.region = '<region>';

        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId : '...', // your identity pool id here
            Logins : {
                // Change the key below according to the specific region your user pool is in.
                'cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<YOUR_USER_POOL_ID>' : result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
            }
        });

        // Instantiate aws sdk service objects now that the credentials have been updated.
        // example: var s3 = new AWS.S3();

    },

    onFailure: function(err) {
        alert(err);
    },

});
```

So far so good. However, now in any subsequent call I do not want to sent

```
var authenticationData = {
Username : 'username',
Password : 'password',
};
```

and instead I want to use the sts token to authenticate the user:

```
var authenticationData = {
    sts: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
};
var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
```

I do not see any example or usage of such a case. Is cognito the right service for this scenario and if yes how can I do the authentication check with sts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials in your authentication callback. That's used if your app needs AWS credentials to access various AWS services.

If your users are only interacting with your own website, the session you get after successful user authentication is valid up to 30 days by default.

You can check if the session is active or not by calling getSession on CognitoUser

https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/blob/9e949c08188f13b8087106564e7b596ec58117ab/src/CognitoUser.js#L826

You can configure that duration by changing Refresh Token Validity for your client in Cognito User Pool console.